# Fine-resolution data causing blocky GGplot line

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to plot some fine resolution data using GGplot. Unfortunately, the plot is very 'blocky' and I am unsure how to fix it. Attached is a photo of the current plot

[image]

I've tired changing the date format, both by importing the data as well as using the 'scale_x_date' argument within ggplot

```
HG$Date<-as.Date(HG$Date, format("%d-%B"))

scale_x_date(date_breaks = "15 day", labels=date_format("%d-%B")
```

I'm trying to produce a 'normal' looking plot that isn't as blocky, but I do not want to use a smoothing tool

Sample Data:

```
Date_Stamp       Date Site.1 Site.2 Site.3 Site.4
1  5/18/2018 22:00 2019-05-18  7e-04 0.0028 0.0034  1e-03
2  5/18/2018 22:30 2019-05-18  7e-04 0.0027 0.0033  1e-03
3  5/18/2018 23:00 2019-05-18  8e-04 0.0029 0.0034  1e-03
4  5/18/2018 23:30 2019-05-18  8e-04 0.0028 0.0033  1e-03
5   5/19/2018 0:00 2019-05-19  7e-04 0.0027 0.0033  1e-03
6   5/19/2018 0:30 2019-05-19  7e-04 0.0029 0.0033  1e-03
8   5/19/2018 1:30 2019-05-19  8e-04 0.0028 0.0033  9e-04
9   5/19/2018 2:00 2019-05-19  8e-04 0.0029 0.0033  9e-04
10  5/19/2018 2:30 2019-05-19  8e-04 0.0028 0.0033  9e-04
```

Comment: Seems like there might be several values per time point. Or put differently, there are duplicates in `HG$Date`.

Comment: The data is recorded at 30 minute intervals, but I left the time out of the date format, would that make a difference?

Comment: Easier to diagnose and fix if you provide [some example data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BrendenDisher: You'd be better off doing a proper downsample, or aggregate the data in some way, if you want coarser time steps.

Comment: Added sample data

Comment: Could you do something like `dput(head(HG, 48*2))`, so we get the data in the same format as you?

Comment: You should also show the code you used to produce the plot.